# How to formulate the constraint If $x = k$, then $y = c$?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

Given are two integer variables $L_x \leq x \leq U_x$ and
$L_y \leq y \leq U_y$. I'd like to formulate the constraint

$$
\text{If} \;\; x = k, \;\; \text{  then  } \;\; y = c,
$$

where $k$ and $c$ are given integer constants. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just to share; If you are using a commercial solver, e.g. CPLEX: `cplex.IfThen(cplex.Eq(x, k), cplex.Eq(y, c));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By introducing the binary helper variables $z_1,z_2,z_3,w_1,w_2,w_3$, you can use the constraints

$$
\begin{align}
L_y z_1 + c z_2 + (c+1)z_3 &\leq y \leq (c-1)z_1 + c z_2 + U_y z_3, \tag{1} \\
L_x w_1 + k w_2 + (k+1)w_3 &\leq x \leq (k-1)w_1 + k w_2 + U_x w_3, \tag{2}\\
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 &= 1, \tag{3}\\
w_1 + w_2 + w_3 &= 1, \tag{4}\\
z_1 + z_3 &\leq w_1 + w_3 \tag{5}.
\end{align}
$$

---

Explanation: The constraint $x = k \implies y = c$ is equivalent to the contraposition $y \neq c \implies x \neq k$. Hence, we want to formulate

$$
y \leq c - 1 \;\vee\; y \geq c+1 \implies x \leq k-1 \; \vee \; x \geq k+1. \tag{*}
$$

Then, (1) and (2) model the constraints

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 = 1 &\implies y \leq c - 1, \\
z_2 = 1 &\implies y = c, \\
z_3 = 1 &\implies y \geq c + 1, \\
w_1 = 1 &\implies x \leq k - 1, \\
w_2 = 1 &\implies x = k, \\
w_3 = 1 &\implies x \geq k + 1, \\
\end{align}
$$

while (3) and (4) guarantee that only one of the three cases for $x$ and $y$ can appear. Finally, (5) expresses constraint (*) by means of the binary helper variables.

Answer (score 5):

In OPL CPLEX this is very easy to read and write.

Let me change https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooifthen.mod to your exact question:

```
(nbBus40==6)=>(nbBus30==3);
```

means nbBus40==6 implies nbBus30==3

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
 
 // with if nb buses 40 is 6 then nb buses 30 is 3
 
 (nbBus40==6)=>(nbBus30==3);
 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Introduce binary variable $\delta$ and we can write following constraints
$$
\begin{align}
k \cdot \delta + L_{x} \cdot (1-\delta) &\le x \le k \cdot \delta + U_{x} \cdot (1-\delta) \\
c \cdot \delta + L_{y} \cdot (1-\delta) &\le y \le c \cdot \delta + U_{y} \cdot (1-\delta) \\
\end{align}
$$
The way it works is when $\delta$ equals $1$, $x = k$ and $y = c$ and when $\delta$ equals 0, they take feasible bounds.

Comment: When $\delta=0$, $L_x \le x \le U_x$ (typo).

Comment: Thank you. Corrected

Comment: Note that this also models the converse statement $y=c \Rightarrow x=k$, which may be too constraining.

Comment: This enforces only $\delta =1\implies (x=k \land y=c)$.  It does not prevent $x=k \land y\not= c$.

Comment: @Kuifje it is actually not constraining enough.  It enforces neither the desired implication nor its converse.

Comment: @RobPratt I agree. This model does not answer the question.

Comment: @RobPratt Can you explain how the case $x = k \land y \neq c$ can occur? I don't see it.

Comment: @hanhu When $\delta=0$, anything can happen.  For example, take $(\delta,x,y)=(0,k,c+1)$.